# How to add 3d object to reference image when tapping on scnplane?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I am trying to 3d object to reference image when user taps on scnplane. I have touches began to scnplane to add new 3d object. Right now i can able to add 3d object but it's not referred to reference image.

My questions is, when user taps scnplane it shows 3d object to reference and tapping on another scnplane to should add new 3d object and removes the older 3d object?

Here is the code i tried:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
            let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name else { return }

        let rotationAsRadian = CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(360))


            // Check To See The Detected Size Of Our Menu Card (Should By 18cm*27cm)
            let menuCardWidth = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
            let menuCardHeight =  imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

            print(
                """
                We Have Detected menu Card With Name \(imageName)
                \(imageName)'s Width Is \(menuCardWidth)
                \(imageName)'s Height Is \(menuCardHeight)
                """)

            let plane = SCNPlane(width: menuCardWidth, height: menuCardHeight)
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.75)

            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 4
            planeNode.runAction(SCNAction.moveBy(x:  0, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 0.75))



            /******************Break fast*******************/

            //BREAKFAST, FALTBREADS, SANDWICHES, ALLDAY
            let labelPlane = SCNPlane(width: 0.065, height: 0.015)
            labelPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "BREAKFAST")

            let lableNode = SCNNode(geometry: labelPlane)
            self.lableNode = lableNode
            lableNode.name = "lableNode"
            lableNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            lableNode.runAction(SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0.2, y: 0, z: -0.125, duration: 0))
     node.addChildNode(lableNode)

            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

   }
    }


   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //1. Get The Current Touch Location & Perform An ARSCNHitTest To Check For Any Hit SCNNode's
    guard let currentTouchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self.sceneView),
        let hitTestNode = self.sceneView.hitTest(currentTouchLocation, options: nil).first?.node else { return }


    if let lableName = hitTestNode.name {
        print("touch working")
        if lableName == "lableNode"{

            makeCakeOnNode(hitTestNode)


        }
    }
}


func makeCakeOnNode(_ node: SCNNode){




                    let overlayNode = self.getNode(withImageName: "imageName")
                    print("overlay::\(overlayNode)")

                    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(overlayNode)


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created new scnplane and added 3d object as child of new scnplane

```
       func makeCakeOnNode(_ node: SCNNode){

    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.18  , height: 0.15)
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1)

    planeNode0 = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
    planeNode0?.runAction(SCNAction.moveBy(x: -0.2, y: -0.15, z: 0, duration: 0))

                    let overlayNode = self.getNode(withImageName: "menu")
                    print("overlay::\(overlayNode)")



    if planeBool == true {

        planeNode1?.isHidden = true
        node.addChildNode(planeNode0!)
        planeNode0?.addChildNode(overlayNode)
        planeBool = false

    } else {

        print("plane removed")
        planeNode0?.isHidden = true

        planeBool = true
    }


}
```

Now it works fine!!